# Restoring Evolution email data files after upgrade

Tags: files, evolution, restore

I just upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS via a bootable USB flash drive.

I now have to start over and get everything back to looking like it did before the upgrade. When installing Evolution it asks if I want to restore files? There are two places I know of that have related data files:

1. Backup archive-  recently backed up [.gpg] files stored on a separate hard drive
2. /Home/user/.config/evolution

Is there a way to restore the link to the evolution files under .config or should I use the .gpg backup files? How do you retrieve the necessary files out of the archive if that is the way to proceed?

Comment: The `~/.config/evolution` location is not the only one to consider here. For reference, please take a look at [Copying Evolution emails from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/250763/68291#250779), [Restore an evolution file](http://askubuntu.com/q/98723/68291#150872), and also other [questions containing 'evolution migration'](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bevolution%5D+migration).